# Effect of Buffer Size in File I/O in Unix

Tags: c, linux, unix, io

I am trying to understand the inner workings of `Unix` based OSs. I was reading on buffered I/O, and how the buffer size affects the number of system calls made, which in turn affects the total time taken by say, a copy program. To being with, here is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>

long currentTimeMillis();

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int bufsize = atoi(argv[3]);
    printf("copying with buffer size %d\n", bufsize);
    char buf[bufsize];
    //open the file
    int fd_from = open(argv[1], O_RDWR);
    if(-1 == fd_from) {
        printf("Error opening source file\n");
        return -1;
    }
    //file to be copied to
    int fd_to = open(argv[2], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    if(-1 == fd_to) {
        printf("Error opening destination file\n");
        return -1;
    }
    //copy
    long startTime = currentTimeMillis();
    int bytes_read = 0;

    long totalTimeForRead = 0;
    long totalTimeForWrite = 0;

    while(1) {

        long readStartTime = currentTimeMillis();
        int bytes_read = read(fd_from,buf,bufsize);
        long readEndTime = currentTimeMillis();
        if(0 == bytes_read) {
            break;
        }
        if(-1 == bytes_read) {
            printf("Error occurred while reading source file\n");
            return -1;
        }

        totalTimeForRead += readEndTime - readStartTime;

        long writeStartTime = currentTimeMillis();
        int bytes_written = write(fd_to,buf,bufsize);
        long writeEndTime = currentTimeMillis();
        totalTimeForWrite += (writeEndTime - writeStartTime);

        if(-1 == bytes_written) {
            printf("Some error occurred while writing file\n");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    long endTime = currentTimeMillis();
    printf("Total time to copy%ld\n", endTime - startTime);
    printf("Total time to write%ld\n", totalTimeForWrite);
    printf("Total time to read%ld\n", totalTimeForRead);

}

long currentTimeMillis() {
  struct timeval time;
  gettimeofday(&time, NULL);
  return time.tv_sec * 1000 + time.tv_usec / 1000;
}
```

I am using a 16G MacBook Pro with 2.9GHz Intel i7 (if this information would be useful). The size of source file is 2.8G. I was a bit surprised to see that total time take by `read()` is much smaller than `write()`. Here're my findings with a buffer size of 16K:

```
./a.out largefile dest 16382
copying with buffer size 16382
Total time to copy5987
Total time to write5330
Total time to read638
```

From what I have read, `write()` returns immediately after transferring the data to the kernel buffer from the user buffer. So the time taken by it is this time + the time taken for the system call initiation. `read()` also reads from kernel buffer to user buffer, so the total time taken should be same (in both cases, there is no disk I/O).

Why is it then that there is such drastic difference in the results? Or am I benchmarking it wrong? Final question: Is it alright to do such benchmarking on a SSD, which has limited write cycles?

Comment: The results are [not a surprise](https://www.enterprisestorageforum.com/storage-hardware/ssd-vs-hdd-speed.html). If the SSD is recent, doing many writes should be ok, but you should check the manufacturer website.

Comment: Would I get different results (relative times) if I used a disk? Also, I know that SSDs are fast. But why is there such a drastic difference in read vs. write times?